# Confused about certain sentences from Wallace’s book Everything And More

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was reading *Everything and More* by David Foster Wallace and I have a few questions regarding the following passage:

> The Promethean myth gives scientists a reason to put on priestly airs and, by hinting at the perhaps **not-so-priestly stances** of their counterparts in other countries, **haul down defense grants**. And it gives non-scientists an implicit pitchfork to brandish in the scientists’ faces. Accordingly, a kind of deal has been struck in which both scientists and non-scientists have ended up accepting the Promethean myth as being a passable model of reality. Call this the Promethean consensus. The Promethean consensus is something that no one would ever admit to believing in, if you pinned them down and tried to get them to engage in that level of introspection, but is universally hammered home by every movie and television Introduction show about science and a good many books as well, and obviously underlies the public postures that scientists are expected to adopt.

What does "not-so-priestly stances" mean?
And what does "haul down defense grants" mean?

I know the meaning of these words, but when they are put together forming a sentence, I find myself very confused.

Comment: It's confusing. The "not-so-priestly stances” are anything the enemy stands for compared to our pure-hearted scientists. Based on these arguments, scientists are able to get government money (“haul down defense grants”).

Comment: There is nothing unclear here **so far as the use of the language is concerned**. Explaining the substantive point of a specific text is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Wallace is famously hard to understand. You might find people suggesting interpretations at https://literature.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've found the sense 'befitting a priest' for 'priestly'. Can you find this definition? It should be in the question. Can you think what attributes this would include? Whence 'not-so-priestly'. // 'Haul down' probably means 'secure', 'manage to get out of the Government'. Is it given in any dictionary?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about interpreting the meaning of passages of literature. It would be appropriate to ask it on [literature.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that most of your confusion comes from the first sentence:
"The Promethean myth gives scientists a reason to put on priestly airs and, by hinting at the perhaps not-so-priestly stances of their counterparts in other countries, haul down defense grants."

In this case, "not-so-priestly" means being unlike a priest, and "haul down defense grants" seems to refer to receiving grants for funding your research.

To parse out the entire sentence: 
"The Promethean myth encourages scientists to pretend that they are pure religious figures, as a priest would be. It also encourages them to attempt to subtly slander their fellow scientists. By doing this, the scientists are able to secure funding for their projects.